# Hard justify content

Tags: html, css

I try to justify a text in an "extreme" way.

That is, I'm looking for that:

[image: first capture]

And not this:

[image: second capture]

which leaves a visible space in the lower right.

To me after to balance so that the words do not stretch.

Additional complication, I would like it to be responsive, and that depending on the size of the screen, there is never any white.

I of course tried the porpriety css `text-align:justify` but it is not enough.

I even go to try Masonry, but without success because the text does not determine the width of the bricks.

Comment: Please add some code for better understanding of whats happening...

Comment: There is a reason that 'justify' works this way. What would you expect to see if there was only 1 or 2 words in the final line? It is possible to do but you will get strange results depending on the length of the text. http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/7yfeqbdj/2/

Comment: ... and this won't work in all browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-align-last

Comment: Thanks, I know it can have a strange effect, but it meets my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this:

```
text-align: justify;
text-align-last: justify;
```